# I have two lists in a for loop and I want to format the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get user input for relatives kind and name.

```
for relatives in victim['other_relatives_kind'], victim['other_relatives_name']:
    print(relatives)
```

If a user inputs, for example, Brother and Aunt in `['other_relatives_kind']` and Andreas Petersen and Anni Nielsen in `['other_relatives_name']` the I get this output:

```
['Brother', 'Aunt']

['Andreas Petersen', 'Anni Nielsen']
```

How can I get the output to be like:

> Brother: Andreas Petersen
>
> Aunt: Anni Nielsen

There might be an "unlimited" numbers of entered relatives.

Comment: The function you are looking for is `zip`.

Comment: What does `fx` mean?

Comment: You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join a `list` of `strs` using any arbirary separator (such a ", "). E.g. `', '.join(['alice', 'bob',' charlie']) # => 'alice, bob, charlie'` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Comment: @Robᵩ For example :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join a list of `str`s using any arbirary separator.

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to merge two lists into a single list, each element of which is a tuple of two items.

Here is an example using `zip` and `str.join()`:

```
victim = {
    'other_relatives_kind': ['Brother', 'Aunt'],
    'other_relatives_name': ['Andreas Petersen', 'Anni Nielsen']
}

zipped_data = zip(
    victim['other_relatives_kind'],
    victim['other_relatives_name'])
print ('\n'.join('{kind}: {name}'.format(kind=kind, name=name)
                 for kind, name in zipped_data))
```

Result:

```
Brother: Andreas Petersen
Aunt: Anni Nielsen
```

Note that the `print` call can be simplified in Python3.6+, using f-strings:

```
print ('\n'.join(f'{kind}: {name}' for kind, name in zipped_data))
```